# How to make a connectionString to connect ado.net c# to on virtualmachine running SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, database-connection

I'm having some difficulties to connect to SQL Server running on a virtual machine (virtualbox). I'm using ADO.NET in C# to do the connection through a connection string but I'm not having any success with this.

My `app.config` file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" />
    </startup>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="AP3"
         connectionString="Data Source=190.166.2.8,1433;Initial Catalog=AP3;
                           User Id=sa;Password=PasswOrd;"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

I don't know if I'm doing anything wrong.

Comment: What - if any - error message do you get? How are you trying to connect, in your C# code? You're not giving us very much to go on .... also: which **version** (2012, 2014, 2016, 2017, 2019) and which **edition** (Express, Developer, Standard, Enterprise) of SQL Server is this for?

Comment: Since you don't provide any useful information beyond "not having success", suggest you start with the MS [connection trouble shooter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/troubleshoot-connecting-to-the-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you've not allowed Sql Server for Remote Connections. Kindly follow this [link](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/setting-up-management-studio-for-remote-sql-server) for more details

Answer (score 0):

You can add DBMSSOCN  to use TCP/IP instead of Named Pipes.Maybe it is a problem.

try this connection string.

```
"Data Source=190.166.2.8,1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=AP3; User Id=sa;Password=PasswOrd;"
```

Comment: Can you add a bit of explanation as to **what** you have changed, and **why** that should solve the OP's problem?